# blitting moving images in pygame

Tags: pygame, blit

First time making something in pygame...
I i'm trying to generate several instances of an image and then scroll them bottom to top. For some reason the original imagestays put while the other imagemove as expected. I am also trying to generate instances of the image on the leftmost quarter of the screen or the rightmost quarter. My images only show up on the left. My gameDisplay is 1150x500 pixels.
Any tips on how i can correct my code would be greatly appreciated!

here's the method i'm using:

```
def gameHighScore():  
    points=0
    guesses=0
    time=0

    balloons= pygame.image.load("balloons.png") 

    objects=[]

    for i in range (4):
        xpos= random.randrange(0, round(display_width/4)) or random.randrange(round((3/4)*display_width), display_width)
        #object generated at start height 400, random xpos with a speed -i*2
        o=Balloons(balloons, 400, xpos ,-i*2)           
        objects.append(o) 


    gamehs=True
    while gamehs:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:   # space for continue
                    paused=False
                    gameTimer.start()
                elif event.key==pygame.K_q: #q for quit
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()



        for o in objects:
            gameDisplay.fill(BLACK)
            message_to_screen("HIGH SCORE", WHITE, y_displace=-100, size="large")
            message_to_screen(" You scored " +str(points) +" points", WHITE, y_displace=0, size="medium")
            message_to_screen("in " +str(time) +" after " +str(guesses) +" guesses", WHITE, y_displace=50, size="medium")
            button("Play (space bar)", 300,400,250,50, GRAY, BLUE, action ="continue")
            button("Quit (Q)", 600,400,250,50, GRAY, BLUE, action ="quit")
        for o in objects:
            o.move()
            gameDisplay.blit(o.image, o.pos)


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)              #static screen, no need for high fps
```

And here's the class that moves objects:

```
class Balloons:

    def __init__(self, image, height, xpos, speed):
        self.speed=speed
        self.image=image
        self.xpos=xpos
        self.pos=image.get_rect().move(xpos, height)             #momve(x,y) change x to random

    def move(self):
        self.pos=self.pos.move(0, self.speed)
        if self.pos.top< -200:
            self.pos.bottom=800
```

Answer (score 1):

There's several things going on here.

Particularly, there are a few things wrong with this line...

```
xpos= random.randrange(0, round(display_width/4)) or random.randrange(round((3/4)*display_width), display_width)
```

`(3/4)` evaluates to ZERO because they are integers. But the larger problem is your use of `or`, which is not doing what you think it is doing. `or` will take the first expression on the left and use it unless it is False. Since this will only be False in the event of randrange picking 0, the right hand side will never get evaluated. I would do something like this...

```
# pick a random position in a quarter-size of the screen.
xpos = int(random.random() * display_width / 4)

# 50% chance of offsetting that position to the right quarter of the screen.
if random.random() < .5: xpos += display_width * 3 / 4
```

Regarding why one of your image always stays put: you are assigning speed based on `for i in range(4)`. The value of `i` for one of the images is 0 and so the speed will be 0.

Comment: `3/4` does not evaluate to 0 if it's Python 3 (which I believe it is since the class doesn't inherit from object). Also, is it not more clear to do an if-else-statement? Then you don't have to assign a value twice. Although, that might just be a matter of opinion. Great answer otherwise, +1